# Error in loading library using JNI in windows

Tags: java, java-native-interface

We have a combination of Java and C++ in software code. So we call C++ library baiscally .dll and .so from JAVA using JNI.
On solaris this works fine. We are able to load .so and call C++ function from Java methods but on windows we get r6034 windows error that unsupportd way to load library.

Can anyone please help me here?

I have already created java.exe.manifest and added it to %JAVA_HOME%/bin.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: [Is that helpful ?](http://cowwoc.blogspot.fr/2008/09/fixing-visual-studio-run-time-error.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest is required for your dll, not for java.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is java.exe.manifest file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50727.4053' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Other code is big around 50+ files but it got compiled. C++ code is working fine without JNI and even Java classes got compiled. Problem happens only when Java tries to load dll.

Comment: One more thing. Code is builded on windows 2003 X64 Service Pack 2 machine with Visual Studio 2005 and JDK 1.5 but I am running it on windows 2008 R2 with JDK 1.6